# polyhedrons congruent if faces are all congruent + same connection status?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, polyhedra, congruences-geometry

In 2 dimension, a unit square and a unit rhombus(of certain angle) has the same list of edges and connection status.
But the unit square and the unit rhombus are not generally  congruent.

Can we find such example in 3 dimension ?
I feel it is much harder to find such example in 3d.

I'll express it in more precise way :

Let A be a convex polyhedron and let L be unordered list of all faces of A. Let B be a convex polyhedron and let M be unordered list of all faces of B.

Suppose that L = M and there is 1-1 correspondence between L and M that preserves the connection status. (the term connection status is a little vague but I think we can define them logically precisely)
Then can we say A is congruent to B ?

Comment: If "same connection status" means $L$ and $M$ have the same [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(polyhedron)), then yes. This is [Cauchy's rigidity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(geometry)).

Comment: Thank you! Fast and correct answer!

Comment: If "same connection status" means that the faces are arranged the same way where they meet at each vertex, then no. Consider the rhombicuboctahedron and the pseudorhombicuboctahedron.